# OSX: Just ran sudo make install ... where did the compiled Phoenix2 app go?

Tags: python, macos, makefile, osx-mountain-lion, bitcoin

I'm a Windows guy who just compiled my first python application,  can anyone tell me where the compiled output would end up?

I just ran `SUDO make install` to install pyopenCL which is a dependency.

Now I'm trying to install and run [phoenix2](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=75786.0;all) and I ran the following:

`sudo python ./setup.py install`

and now I'm not sure [where to look for and execute the file as described here](http://bitcoinpool.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=129).  Any assistance would be appreciated (I'm a bit of a n00b here, overwhelmed by all the documentation)

Comment: You will need to add some further description on what did you do. Is the application yours or publicly available? What did you use to compile it (aka what did you type)? etc as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask (Be specific) ;-)

Comment: @ssice Update the question, but alyu got me on the right track..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `make install`, the `make` application looks in the project's `Makefile` to find out where it should put executables, as well as any other files the application needs to run. This, of course, assumes that the project even has executables (a library might not, for example).

Look in the project base directory (the dir you ran `make install` from) for a file named `Makefile`. It should have a variable called `BIN_DIR` or similar that tells you where it wants final binaries to go.